# glGenerateMipmap or glGenerateMipmapEXT

Tags: opengl

I need glGenerateMipmap* function, but I would like to know if there are any differences between:`glGenerateMipmap` and `glGenerateMipmapEXT`?

I understand that EXT was before ARB so EXT version should work on older hardware? Are there any differences in behavior?

another question:

Can I use:

```
myGLGenerateMipmap = loadProcAddress("glGenerateMipmap")
```

or I should check support for the `GL_EXT_framebuffer_object` first?

please note that I would not like to use GLEW/GLEE or any other libraries...

Comment: I know you say you'd prefer not to use a library, but boy do they save you a lot of trouble for this sort of thing.

Comment: @fen ,can you explain why you don't want to use extension loading library?

Comment: @MichaelIV This code is part of some legacy code and I do not want to add another dependency like GLEW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until OpenGL 3.0, this function was not a part of the OpenGL spec. proper. The version that is included in OpenGL 3.0 is actually derived from the `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object` specification.

If your driver lists the `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object` extension, or you know you have a legitimate OpenGL 3.0+ implementation, you are guaranteed to have this functionality through the proc. address `glGenerateMipmap`. This is the procedure you shoud use, in such a case.

`glGenerateMipmapEXT` comes from the awful EXT version of the FBO specification. I would avoid it like the plague, unless you have neither OpenGL 3.0 nor `GL_ARB_framebuffer_object`. You will not have this procedure either, however, if your driver does not report `GL_EXT_framebuffer_object`.

This is where extension wranglers make life easier... but I can see not wanting to add another dependency to your software. You are going to have to study up on the art of reading extension specifications and follow the version change history on the [OpenGL® Registry](http://www.opengl.org/registry)